# How to show picture in MonoDroid

Tags: imageview, xamarin.android, image

i just looked at monodroid and am trying to figure out very simple.  i want to click either of two buttons and depending on button pushed, display picture.  using the samples/tutorials, i have done the buttons.  Does anyone have a simple example of how to show picture?  Guessing its ImageView, but haven't found any example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an [ImageView](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.Widget.ImageView) in your layout like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/Icon" />
```

This will set the image to be a drawable resource named Icon. You can also set it from C# using the [SetImageResource](http://docs.mono-android.net/monodoc.ashx?link=M%3aAndroid.Widget.ImageView.SetImageResource%28System.Int32%29) method:

```
var image = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Image);
image.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
```

Depending on where you want to pull the image from there are other methods on ImageView that might help, such as [SetImageURI](http://docs.mono-android.net/monodoc.ashx?link=M%3aAndroid.Widget.ImageView.SetImageURI%28Android.Net.Uri%29) or [SetImageDrawable](http://docs.mono-android.net/monodoc.ashx?link=M%3aAndroid.Widget.ImageView.SetImageDrawable%28Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable%29).